# Is there a way to terminate TestExecute process when aborting Jenkins build manually?

Tags: jenkins, testcomplete

I would like to know, if there is a possibility to terminate TestExecute (or in fact any) process when I manually abort the building job in Jenkins via the red X button. Often happen, that someone starts a new build with incorrect parameters, and it needs to be aborted. But when I abort the build in Jenkins, it just frees up the executor, but on the server the TestExecute process keeps running, and executing the tests.